# Fetch .clang-format file in pre-commit framework at install

Tags: c++, git, clang-format, pre-commit.com

We have a repository in which we want to introduce [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) framework and override the previous git pre-hooks. We want to run pre-commit on different languages and we will be using [clang-format](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-clang-format) to format C++ code. Now I had one question, since we would need to keep the `.clang-format` file in the root of the repo where we will also add our `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file. Is there a way to get this file downloaded into our repo the first time `pre-commit install` command is executed so as to keep this file at one place and copy in multiple repos. Any hep would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't -- but one idea that you could do (this is mostly a sketch, not fully fleshed out) would be to make a repository which houses your "canonical" formatting configuration

you'd [set up a pre-commit manifest as usual](https://pre-commit.com/#creating-new-hooks) (similar to the one that's in the `mirrors-clang-format` repository)

you'd also create a small python package which has a resource file containing your clang format.

the small python package would also depend on the `clang-format` pypi package

this small python package could then execute `clang-format` and pass along the path to the resource file for the clang formatting configuration

that said, this is probably not a good idea -- part of the reason for configuration is so that individual repositories can diverge to meet their needs.  this solution would assume that every repository would perfectly match the exact linter configuration and that seems exceedingly unlikely

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping in this. Makes sense. One more question that I had Anthony is that we have the below clang-format and prettier as hooks right now. Whenever I modify a .cpp file which goes against my .clang-format file, it is automatically fixed and the hook passes but for prettier it fails and updates the changes for you to look at. Shouldn't both fail?

Comment: if it makes modifications it'll fail -- is it possible that prettier is formatting first?

Comment: Ummm. I have clang-format first in the .yml file and the prettier. And they run in order. Prettier fails but not clang-format. Intreating.